# "Merging" tables in Access Web App using Data Macro

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-data-macro

I have built an Access Web App (2013) to keep track of device inventory for a client. They want to be able to mass-update the database using Excel spreadsheets that are generated from orders. I already know that there is no way to import/update data into an existing table in AWA, so I am attempting to build a data macro that will compare an imported table to the existing table, and add new records, or edit existing ones.

For right now, I am just trying to get the first part to work - add new records. However, no matter what I try, my data macro keeps giving me the error "Access can't convert the value of 'N/A' to the specified data type."

I have run a trace on the macro, and it shows that it goes through each step perfectly until the very end - it will create the new record, set the 2 fields I am testing with... and then try to create the record again. It gets stuck because it doesn't go back up to the next "For Each Record" loop for the imported table. I have tried doing a "Stop Macro" after the Create Record to see if I could get it to just do the first record, but it still tries to run again and fails.

I found on one page someone who said ["Data Macros forbid the use of “CreateRecord cannot be used inside of a ForEachRecord”](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/how-to-insert-multiple-records-in-child-table-with/3007e57a-cfb0-4777-bc68-ded553554eb4)" but I haven't found anything to back that up anywhere.

I do not have enough reputation points to post images or even link to them, unfortunately, so I am going to try to accurately represent my macro and trace below (please excuse my relative newness to the site :( ).

My Macro looks as such:

```
For Each Record In ImportTest
      Where Condition
   SetLocalVar
              Name IsMatch
              Expression = 0
   Look Up A Record In Inventory List
            Where Condition = [InventoryList].[SerialNumber]=[ImportTest].[Serial Number]
      SetLocalVar
                  Name IsMatch
                  Expression = 1
  If [IsMatch]=0 Then
     Create a Record In Inventory List
        Set Field
            Name InventoryList.BuildingName
            Value = 1
        Set Field
            Name InventoryList.SerialNumber
            Value = [ImportTest].[Serial Number]
  End If
```

So to explain what my goal was, in case I did it wrong: The "For Each Record In ImportTest" is looking through the imported table (no where condition because I want all of them). The first "SetLocalVar IsMatch" is to give the macro a way to know if the serial number in the import table matches another record in the existing InventoryList table (this is where I would then update that record, once I get it all working). Next is my "If [IsMatch]=0" which checks to see if a matching record was ever found (would've been set to 1 if it had found the match before). Since no match is found, it creates a record in InventoryList using the current record that the For Each Record loop is pointed at. I actually have many other fields that will be set, but these two are just for my proof of concept (my InventoryList requires these two fields). At this point, it should finish adding the record, then hit the end of the loop, and start anew. However, my trace shows "CreateRecord" throwing an SQL exception:

```
MacroName-ActionName-Operand-Output-TargetRow-RuntimeErrorMessage
ImportMacro-ForEachRecord-ImportTest;---
ImportMacro-ForEachRecord---[ID] = 1 ; [Serial Number] = TESTTEST1 ; [Building Name] = Glendaal Elementary School-
ImportMacro-SetLocalVar-IsMatch-0.000000--
ImportMacro-LookupRecord-InventoryList;WHERE [InventoryList].[SerialNumber]=[ImportTest].[Serial Number]---
ImportMacro-If-[IsMatch]=0---
ImportMacro-CreateRecord----
ImportMacro-If-[ImportTest].[Building Name]="Glendaal Elementary School"---
ImportMacro-SetField-InventoryList.BuildingName-1--
ImportMacro-SetField-InventoryList.SerialNumber-TESTTEST1--
ImportMacro-CreateRecord----SQL exception
```

I can't figure out why it's doing this last "CreateRecord" that throws the exception. Does anyone see what I may have missed, or have suggestions for how to proceed?

Thanks in advance to all who help.
~SetsunaMH

Current version of ImportTest data macro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2010/12/application"><DataMacro><Statements><ForEachRecord><Data><Reference>ImportTest</Reference></Data><Statements><Action Name="SetLocalVar"><Argument Name="Name">IsMatch</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>0</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="0"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><LookUpRecord><Data><Reference>InventoryList</Reference><WhereCondition><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[SerialNumber]=[ImportTest].[Serial Number]</Original><FunctionCall Name="="><Identifier Name="InventoryList.SerialNumber" Index="0"/><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Serial Number" Index="1"/></FunctionCall></Expression></WhereCondition></Data><Statements><Action Name="SetLocalVar"><Argument Name="Name">IsMatch</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>1</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="1"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action></Statements></LookUpRecord><ConditionalBlock><If><Condition><Expression><Original>[IsMatch]=0</Original><FunctionCall Name="="><Identifier Name="IsMatch" Index="0"/><IntegerLiteral Value="0" Index="1"/></FunctionCall></Expression></Condition><Statements><CreateRecord><Data><Reference>InventoryList</Reference></Data><Statements><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.BuildingName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>1</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="1"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.SerialNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Serial Number]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Serial Number"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Model</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>8</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="8"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.RoomDescription</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>1</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="1"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Manufacturer</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>1</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="1"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.DeviceName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Device Name]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Device Name"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.ImagePackage</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Image Package]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Image Package"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.NeedsVerification</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Needs Verification]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Needs Verification"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.NewLocation</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[New Location]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.New Location"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.OneOffs</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[One Offs]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.One Offs"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.PurchasedDate</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Purchased Date]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Purchased Date"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Retired</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Retired]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Retired"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Software1</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>67</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="67"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Software2</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>67</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="67"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Software3</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>67</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="67"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Software4</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>67</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="67"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Software5</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>67</Original><IntegerLiteral Value="67"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Staff-Student</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Staff-Student]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Staff-Student"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Swap</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Swap]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Swap"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.TagNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Tag Number]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Tag Number"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.TopUser</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Top User]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Top User"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Warranty</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[ImportTest].[Warranty]</Original><Identifier Name="ImportTest.Warranty"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.Comments</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>"Test"</Original><StringLiteral Value="Test"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.CreatedBy</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>"Test"</Original><StringLiteral Value="Test"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">InventoryList.UpdatedBy</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>""</Original><StringLiteral Value=""/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action></Statements></CreateRecord></Statements></If></ConditionalBlock></Statements></ForEachRecord></Statements></DataMacro></DataMacros>
```

Current On Update macro for InventoryList Table (currently is stopped so as to not cause issues and to not overload my AuditTrail table while everything is in development. This macro was tested with multiple people using the database at once and works like a charm).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2010/12/application"><DataMacro Event="AfterUpdate"><Statements><Comment>Macro is stopped to not overload AuditTrail during changes made to initial data.</Comment><Action Name="StopMacro"/><Comment>Save the Old values</Comment><CreateRecord><Data><Reference>AuditTrail</Reference></Data><Statements><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.OldNew</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>"Old"</Original><StringLiteral Value="Old"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.RecordID</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[ID]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.ID"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Timestamp</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>Now()</Original><FunctionCall Name="Now"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.ChangedBy</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[UpdatedBy]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.UpdatedBy"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.BuildingName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[BuildingName]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.BuildingName"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.RoomDescription</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[RoomDescription]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.RoomDescription"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Manufacturer</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Manufacturer]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Manufacturer"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Model</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Model]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Model"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.DeviceName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[DeviceName]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.DeviceName"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.TopUser</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[TopUser]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.TopUser"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Staff-Student</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Staff-Student]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Staff-Student"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.SerialNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[SerialNumber]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.SerialNumber"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.TagNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[TagNumber]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.TagNumber"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.PurchasedDate</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[PurchasedDate]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.PurchasedDate"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Warranty</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Warranty]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Warranty"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.ImagePackage</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[ImagePackage]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.ImagePackage"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Swap</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Swap]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Swap"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.NewLocation</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[NewLocation]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.NewLocation"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Retired</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Retired]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Retired"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.OneOffs</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[OneOffs]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.OneOffs"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Comments</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[Comments]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.Comments"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.NeedsVerification</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[Old].[NeedsVerification]</Original><Identifier Name="Old.NeedsVerification"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action></Statements></CreateRecord><Comment>Save the New values</Comment><CreateRecord><Data><Reference>AuditTrail</Reference></Data><Statements><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.OldNew</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>"New"</Original><StringLiteral Value="New"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.RecordID</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[ID]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.ID"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Timestamp</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>Now()</Original><FunctionCall Name="Now"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.ChangedBy</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[UpdatedBy]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.UpdatedBy"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.BuildingName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[BuildingName]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.BuildingName"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.RoomDescription</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[RoomDescription]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.RoomDescription"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Manufacturer</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Manufacturer]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Manufacturer"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Model</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Model]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Model"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.DeviceName</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[DeviceName]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.DeviceName"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.TopUser</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[TopUser]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.TopUser"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Staff-Student</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Staff-Student]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Staff-Student"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.SerialNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[SerialNumber]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.SerialNumber"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.TagNumber</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[TagNumber]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.TagNumber"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.PurchasedDate</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[PurchasedDate]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.PurchasedDate"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Warranty</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Warranty]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Warranty"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.ImagePackage</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[ImagePackage]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.ImagePackage"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Swap</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Swap]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Swap"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.NewLocation</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[NewLocation]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.NewLocation"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Retired</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Retired]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Retired"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.OneOffs</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[OneOffs]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.OneOffs"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.Comments</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[Comments]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.Comments"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action><Action Name="SetField"><Argument Name="Field">AuditTrail.NeedsVerification</Argument><ExpressionArgument Name="Value"><Expression><Original>[InventoryList].[NeedsVerification]</Original><Identifier Name="InventoryList.NeedsVerification"/></Expression></ExpressionArgument></Action></Statements></CreateRecord></Statements></DataMacro></DataMacros>
```

Comment: Your scenario sounds quite logical; I just helped another customer in a different forum with the same type of scenario. Let's first dig into more detail about the data types in your two tables here. Can you list out the needed fields and their data types from the table Design view for each of the two tables? Thanks.

Comment: For the InventoryList table:

BuildingName is a lookup to another table
SerialNumber is a short text

For the ImportTest Table: 

BuildingName is a short text (hence the translating this to 1 which is the ID for the relevant building)
SerialNumber is a short text.

Sorry that updated a few times... I kept pressing enter without catching shift a few times D:

Comment: Ok, that helps but it is inconsistent with your macro logic. Your macro logic posted earlier indicates some of the fields have spaces in the names and others don't. In order for me to build an exact repro of your setup I need the exact schema and logic. Can you open the data macro, press CTRL+A to highlight everything, press CTRL+C to copy all the logic to the clipboard and then paste it here. (It will just be raw XML.) I will then paste that into my macro window. Thanks.

Comment: added the XML above - it was too long for a comment. Please note that this is slightly different than what was explained above (really wish I could've posted screenshots... grr) because I have been fiddling with it to try and find if it broke because of a specific field or not - it always breaks after all fields are set, not on any one specific one.

Comment: Ok perfect, just what I needed. For the time being don't make any more changes while I recreate this in my test environment.

Comment: I've recreated the data macro in my sample and all the fields you have listed so far in the macro logic. For the time being I also created a third "Buildings" table so I could properly create a lookup field for the BuildingName field in InventoryList. I plugged in some sample data and it ran without any errors. What error are you getting when you run this macro as-is now?

Comment: I still get the "Access can't convert the value of 'N/A' to the specified data type." error when the macro is run. I have double-checked than none of my other fields are required in order for a record to be created, but it looks like it keeps wanting to add more fields. I think I am going to try putting all the fields in and see if it still throws the sql exception. I was hoping I wouldn't have to, because there are about 30 fields in total :( I will respond back on Monday with how that goes.

Comment: Sounds to me like a data issue. Things to look for would be field property settings, field/table level validation rules, indexes, null values, and even perhaps a data macro attached to the OnInsert event of InventoryList. All of these could be at play here with preventing the data insert. One thing to try would be just have one test record in ImportTest and see if that works. Let me know how this goes; I'm sure we can get this fixed. I also see a way to improve your current macro logic of handling the lookup field data insert. I had to do something similar for a large app here at Microsoft.

Comment: Well, I added all the fields to my create record section, and now its not even making it to the SetField pieces of the macro. It checks If IsMatch = 0, then says "If" and throws the SQL exception again. (I keep hitting enter, ack!). I do have "On Update" macro running on my InventoryList, but with all the fields populated, it shouldn't effect anything. I am still getting the "cannot convert N/A" to the specified data type" error when the macro is run.

Comment: Can you post your current full macro logic now as you have it? I'll try and repro this on my test environment.
Also, can you please post (separately) the macro logic you have for the On Update event of the InventoryList table? I honestly think that may have something to do with this issue.

Comment: added macros to OP. Thanks, Jeff. Note that I've had my Update macro stopped since the beginning - This update macro is fueling my audit trail, which works perfectly, and I don't want it to be overloaded while I play with things, so whenever I start messing with adding lots of data, I turn it off.

Comment: Thanks. Let me play with this for a bit and see if I can diagnose the issue in my test environment.

Comment: Just so you know, I do actually know how to set up the lookups so it will find the correct ID for my lookup fields, I just wanted to get it working, so I input the actual numbers for the test device that I'm trying to add. Once it's really working I can go back and do the "Lookup a record" thing.

Comment: So with the full macro provided, I added in the relevant fields to my two test tables. I don't have all the correct data types you used but in my quick test the full macro runs fine with some data I put into the ImportTest table. Given that you are not executing the OnUpdate macro at the moment because you have the Stop Macro action at the top, we can rule that out for the moment. So now the most logical issue is that the data you have in ImportTest is the issue. Can you search to see if you have N/A anywhere in your data in ImportTest? If so, what field is that data in?

Comment: There is no N/A in the Import Test table except for the Software 1 - 5 fields. In the Inventory table, these fields are a lookup to a Software table - This is why I bypassed for now with entering the ID for N/A in those fields (67) rather than bothering with the whole Lookup a Record song and dance just yet.

Comment: Hummm....interesting. Can you humor me and temporarily add a Where clause to your append data macro such that it tries to import just one record from ImportTest (just use an ID value). Does the append succeed through the data macro with just the one record?

Comment: I only had 1 record in my table to begin with, but I gave it the ID condition anyway just to check. Still got the error. My trace still shows that it is running fine all the way to the If IsMatch=0. The trace then shows an SQL exception on an If. I'm almost wondering at this point if this is a bug/glitch, since I had another If there before to translate the BuildingName to its ID. I think I might try rebuilding the macro from scratch and see if it works, because this makes no sense to me. Especially since I'm doing almost the same thing with my Audit (and it works perfectly when it's running)

Comment: Well, now I'm really stumped. I created an entirely new macro from scratch. Same error message. I decide to try stripping it down to literally just create a record from the other table, no ifs or anything. Still same error. Throws the SQL exception before the CreateRecord even starts (I still need the For Each Record to get into ImportTest). I've even tried creating the record without the Software 1-5 fields being touched because that's the only place N/A shows up... still nothing. I have no clue what could be wrong at this point. :(

Comment: I have now even gone so far as to change the "N/A" in the Software fields in the ImportTest table to "NONE" instead (since the SetField is just using the ID, didn't think it would matter what it actually said). Still got the error. I added a Where condition again to my For Each Record in ImportTest, this time looking to make sure serial number is not null. Still "Can't convert the value of 'N/A' to specified data type." Not a single field in my ImportTest contains "N/A" now. Access, give me better error messages, please? D:

Comment: Very odd indeed. Are you using Office 365 to host your Access web app, or are you using an on-prem SharePoint server within your organization?

Comment: SharePoint Server. I am a part of the Help Desk here, so if there's some higher-end setting that needs to be changed, I at least know the people to ask (whether they'll change it or not is a different story).

Comment: Would you by chance be willing to package up the web app as an app package and sending that to me to look at more closely to see what might be causing the issue? If so, you can leave the option unchecked for including data such that none of your data would be in it. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I can do that (I just can't send the data, of course). Where should I send it? (Don't know if I can send files through the site? I haven't asked many questions here, most of the time my questions are already answered :D )

Comment: Package up the web app as an app package using the option in the Backstage and be sure to not include any data. Access will create a file with a .app extension. Right-click the file and change the extension to .zip. Our email servers will block file extensions of .app so if you change it to .zip then it will come through. Then email it directly to me using my first name, a period, then my last name, the 'at' symbol, then microsoft.com domain. One I receive it and install in my environment, we'll continue the discussion here. Thanks.

Comment: Mail sent from my google account. Let me know if you don't get it and I can send it a different way.

Comment: Perfect, having the actual file helped. I see what is causing the issue. You currently have a Default Value property assigned to each of the Software lookup fields (1-5) in the InventoryList table. I removed those default values for each of those fields. I then put in some sample dummy data into the related tables. Your button on the List view is currently set to run the ImportMacro2 data macro. When I run that now, the macro completes without error and the data is inserted into InventoryList. You can't use N/A as default values because those are lookup fields that only accept IDs (numbers).

Comment: Oh my god, Jeff.... THANK YOU SO SO MUCH!!!! Please do put your solution/explanation as an answer and I will mark it as the answer while I sing you praises. - I actually should have noticed this myself a while ago because I had manually added some new records to InventoryList and they weren't getting the "N/A" software as a default, now that I looked at it closer. I changed the default to 67, which is the ID for my N/A software record, and it worked like a charm! Woo hoo!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear the issue is resolved for you now. I've reposted my information as an Answer now. Good luck with your continued work on Access web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the Access web app package, I've identified what the issues was. You currently have a Default Value property assigned to each of the Software lookup fields (1-5) in the InventoryList table. I removed those default values for each of those fields. I then put in some sample dummy data into the related tables. Your button on the List view is currently set to run the ImportMacro2 data macro. When I run that now, the macro completes without error and the data is inserted into InventoryList. You can't use N/A as default values because those are lookup fields that only accept IDs (numbers).

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I wanted to expand upon what I did to get my import macro working perfectly - With each field that is a lookup to another table, I first have the macro Lookup a Record in it's respective table, looking through the "name" of the record that matches what is in my import table. It stores the ID of the found record in a local variable which I then use later on to populate the correct field in the new record. The same macro has also been fleshed out to edit an existing record, based on if the Serial Number provided is found in the DB already or not.